# How do I use a captured image with react-native-camera

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

I can get the [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera) module to access the camera and save an image. However, I can't figure out how to display this image to the user.

What I'm trying:

Here I take the picture. This generates what looks to be a `.jpg` file in `assets-library://....`

```
    _takePicture() {
        var self = this;
        this.refs.cam.capture(function(err, data) {
          this.setState({photo: data});
          console.log(err, data);
          // data is "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=########-####-####-####-##########&ext=JPG"
          console.log('just took a picture');
        }); 
    }
```

However, If I try to render the image:

```
    render: function() {
      return(
         <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: this.state.photo}}/>
      );
    }
```

I get this error:

`No suitable image URL loader found for assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=.......`

How can I take a photo, save it to the current `state` of my application, and render it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The solution was to enable the [save to disk option](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera#capturetarget) vs. the save to cameraRoll option:

```
<Camera
  captureTarget={Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk}
  // Rest of Camera options here
/>
```

Comment: Camera.constants is coming {}. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

So, I was using the @YPCrumble answer for some time.

But now I have to save the image in my camera roll.

If anyone want to continue saving in camera roll, you have to manually link RTCCameraRoll library.

Documentation to link library here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#manual-linking

It is so simple:

> You can find the RCTImage.xcodeproj in your
>   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CameraRoll
>
> Drag and drop this file inside Libraries folder in your XCode project.
>
> After that, click in your main project, and find in the right pane
>   "Build Phases".
>
> Inside "Link Binary With Libraries", drag and drop the file called
>   "libRCTCameraRoll.a" from left pane -> Libraries ->
>   RTCCameraRoll.xcodeproj -> Products